# URL regex with sub domains

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I am trying to build a regular expression for domains + subdomains.
Unfortunately, I did not manage to define it.

I've built a regex for a regular domain.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}[-]{0,}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}.([a-zA-Z0-9].){2,}(com|co.il|org|co|net|info|biz|org.il|io)$/
```

I want that the user could enter text and dot (ex: "web.") as many times as he wants but it won't be required
also if the user adds another dot, he will be required to add letters / numbers before so it will be a valid sub domain

Comment: Could you provide an example input and what the output should be?

Comment: sub.domain.com OR domain.com OR sub.subsub.domain.com ---> OUTPUT should be true or false. Im using preg_match in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Try following Regular expression:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]*\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*[[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```